# iOS crash report: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) - stringByAppendingString

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, crash-reports

I am trying to fix a bug that I am not able to recreate, it doesn't happen to my device (iPhone 5s) or in any iOS simulator but happened only once in an iPhone 7 of my client. When the client deleted and downloaded again the app, the bug disappeared, so I am searching for a ghost now.

I was able to get the crash log file from the clients phone and symbolicate it. Here are some useful informations I extracted:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0
```

In the un-symbolicated crash report: (check 2 and 3 line)

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x18c92efe0 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x18b390538 objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation                  0x18c92ef28 +[NSException raise:format:] + 116
3   Foundation                      0x18d324df0 -[NSString stringByAppendingString:] + 112
4   myApp                           0x100119ea8 0x100004000 + 1138344
5   myApp                           0x100119784 0x100004000 + 1136516
6   UIKit                           0x192ad1204 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 380
7   UIKit                           0x192cdd738 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3452
8   UIKit                           0x192ce31e0 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1684
9   UIKit                           0x192cf7d18 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.3151 + 48
10  UIKit                           0x192ce0474 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 168
11  FrontBoardServices              0x18e4d7884 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36
12  FrontBoardServices              0x18e4d76f0 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 176
13  FrontBoardServices              0x18e4d7aa0 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
14  CoreFoundation                  0x18c8dd42c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
15  CoreFoundation                  0x18c8dcd9c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
16  CoreFoundation                  0x18c8da9a8 __CFRunLoopRun + 744
17  CoreFoundation                  0x18c80ada4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
18  UIKit                           0x192aca384 -[UIApplication _run] + 652
19  UIKit                           0x192ac5058 UIApplicationMain + 208
20  myApp                           0x10014b8ac 0x100004000 + 1341612
21  libdyld.dylib                   0x18b81959c start + 4
```

and in the symbolicated crash report:(check 4 and 5 line)

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x185f7fd38 0x185e3e000 + 1318200
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x185494528 0x18548c000 + 34088
2   CoreFoundation                  0x185f7fc80 0x185e3e000 + 1318016
3   Foundation                      0x18686e760 0x186862000 + 51040
4   myApp                           0x10469f928 -[AppDelegate initViewController] (AppDelegate.m:96)
5   myApp                           0x10469f520 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (AppDelegate.m:30)
6   UIKit                           0x18f3ff050 0x18f380000 + 520272
7   UIKit                           0x18f5f2898 0x18f380000 + 2566296
8   UIKit                           0x18f5f76e4 0x18f380000 + 2586340
9   UIKit                           0x18f885454 0x18f380000 + 5264468
10  UIKit                           0x18fb551f0 0x18f380000 + 8212976
11  UIKit                           0x18f8850b8 0x18f380000 + 5263544
12  UIKit                           0x18f885928 0x18f380000 + 5265704
13  UIKit                           0x18ffee6e8 0x18f380000 + 13035240
14  UIKit                           0x18ffee58c 0x18f380000 + 13034892
15  UIKit                           0x18fd6a9c0 0x18f380000 + 10398144
16  UIKit                           0x18fefffc8 0x18f380000 + 12058568
17  UIKit                           0x18fd6a870 0x18f380000 + 10397808
18  UIKit                           0x18fb54850 0x18f380000 + 8210512
19  UIKit                           0x18f5f5e28 0x18f380000 + 2580008
20  UIKit                           0x18f9f96ec 0x18f380000 + 6788844
21  FrontBoardServices              0x188621768 0x188615000 + 51048
22  FrontBoardServices              0x18862a070 0x188615000 + 86128
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x185905048 0x185904000 + 4168
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x18590c6c8 0x185904000 + 34504
25  FrontBoardServices              0x188655a04 0x188615000 + 264708
26  FrontBoardServices              0x1886556a8 0x188615000 + 263848
27  FrontBoardServices              0x188655c44 0x188615000 + 265284
28  CoreFoundation                  0x185f28358 0x185e3e000 + 959320
29  CoreFoundation                  0x185f282d8 0x185e3e000 + 959192
30  CoreFoundation                  0x185f27b60 0x185e3e000 + 957280
31  CoreFoundation                  0x185f25738 0x185e3e000 + 948024
32  CoreFoundation                  0x185e462d8 0x185e3e000 + 33496
33  GraphicsServices                0x187cd7f84 0x187ccd000 + 44932
34  UIKit                           0x18f3f3880 0x18f380000 + 473216
35  myApp                           0x1046bc124 main (main.m:14)
36  libdyld.dylib                   0x18596a56c 0x185969000 + 5484
```

So at the third line of the un-symbolicated crash report it says:

```
0x18d324df0 -[NSString stringByAppendingString:] + 112
```

and at the 4th line of the symbolicated crash report:

```
0x10469f928 -[AppDelegate initViewController] (AppDelegate.m:96)
```

In my AppDelegate at the 96 line I have this code:

```
NSString *backColorString = [@"#" stringByAppendingString:[myModel sharedInstance].theme.BackColor];
```

So the only thing that can be wrong with this, if the problem is indeed here(?) is that the

```
[HotelStay sharedInstance].theme.BackColor
```

must return nil or "".

The thing is that I tried both and I couldn't be able to recreate the problem. Is there something I am missing or doing wrong here?

Comment: What if theme was nil instead of backcolor ?

Comment: Yes I tried to put nil but I can't reproduce the exact same screen the Client's phone had when the app was crashing.

Comment: The app was probably in a shit 'in between' state that you won't be able to reproduce. I don't know the scale of this but usually if after a day or trial and error, for a single occurrence, I blame it on luck and go do something else. If you had 300 users having this it would be different, but one person? For all we know the phone was lagging, there was a race condition that you won't reproduce, and it's a one in a million chance to happen again. Keep checking your crash logs for this bug and investigate once you've got more of it. Unless someone can help you on this.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I appreciate it

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use `stringByAppendingString` on an `NSString` than you end up with leaks because the pointer associated with the initial `NSString` moves around, pointing to the new string created by the append, whereas with `NSMutableString`, your pointer always points to that mutable string. I guess it should be the issue but what I am thinking is according to `Apple Documentation` The string to append to the receiver. This value must not be nil if its nil it will Raise a `NSInvalidArgumentException`.

Comment: This is just sick

Comment: But this will happen only once in a very rare occasion. Before my client re-downloaed the app, I told him to kill it and open it again and the bug was still there.

Comment: Yup! even I faced this few time on different devices like crashing with `iPhone6` working fine with `6S` install it again works fine, as you said this is just sick.

Comment: So I guess I have to replace all NSString with NSMutableString in my project that uses stringByAppendingString ?

Comment: This answer makes no sense at all. You do not need to use `NSMutableString` with `stringByAppendingString`. And there are no leaks here.

Comment: @rmaddy please share your thoughts if you have we are happy to accept and up vote your answer. This is what we observed and learned from Apple developer document.